# Create new columns based on number of values in list in other pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, lambda, filter

I have a pandas data frame that looks like

```
country       region           values
   A           CA           [0, 0, 1, .5]
   B           NE           [0, 0, 0, 1]
   C           CA           [1, 1, 1, .5]
   D           CA           [1, 0, 1, .5]
   E           EE           [0, .5, .5, 0]
   F           NE           [0, 1, 1, 1]
   G           EE           [0, 0, 0, 0]
   H           NE           [0, .5, 1, .5] 
   I           EE           [nan, 0]
```

I want to get which countries have all 4 values of 1, .5 ,0 or 3 values of 1, 0, .5, or 2 values of 1, .5, or 0.  The value 1 equals adopted(A), .5 equals partially adopted(PA), and equals not adopted (NA). For example:

```
     country       region      values         #A_all4      #A_any3    #A_any2       #PA_all4       #PA_any3       #PA_any2        
   A           CA           [0, 0, 1, .5]         0            0         0              0                0                0
   B           NE           [0, 0, 0, 1]          0            0         0              0                0                0
   C           CA           [1, 1, 1, .5]         0            1         0              0                0                0
   D           CA           [1, 0, 1, .5]         0            0         1              0                0                0     
   E           EE           [0, .5, .5, 0]        0            0         1              0                0                0
   F           NE           [0, 1, 1, 1]          0            1         0              0                0                1
   G           EE           [0, 0, 0, 0]          0            0         0              0                0                0
   H           NE           [0, .5, 1, .5]        0            0         0              0                0                1
   I           EE           [nan, 0]              0            0         0              0                0                0
```

I want to do this for all values (Adopted, Partially adopted, and Not adopted) I just didn't have the room to do it.  have tried filtering using lambda but it is not giving me the results I need. Any suggestions would be great! Thank you

Comment: Does Country H have #A_any2 set to 1 also, because of the two .5?

Comment: no just, PA_any2 since the values are treated as factors, not numeric

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try:

```
dfi = (df.loc[:, 'values']
         .explode()
         .groupby(level=0)
         .value_counts()
         .rename('count')
         .reset_index())

dfi = dfi.query('values != 0.0 and count > 1')

(df.assign(**pd.crosstab(dfi['level_0'], 
                         dfi['count']).reindex([4,3,2], 
                                               fill_value=0, axis=1)
           .add_prefix('#A_all')).fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
  country region            values  #A_all4  #A_all3  #A_all2
0       A     CA    [0, 0, 1, 0.5]      0.0      0.0      0.0
1       B     NE      [0, 0, 0, 1]      0.0      0.0      0.0
2       C     CA    [1, 1, 1, 0.5]      0.0      1.0      0.0
3       D     CA    [1, 0, 1, 0.5]      0.0      0.0      1.0
4       E     EE  [0, 0.5, 0.5, 0]      0.0      0.0      1.0
5       F     NE      [0, 1, 1, 1]      0.0      1.0      0.0
6       G     EE      [0, 0, 0, 0]      0.0      0.0      0.0
7       H     NE  [0, 0.5, 1, 0.5]      0.0      0.0      1.0
8       I     EE          [nan, 0]      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

Comment: this doesn't help me to get the other values

Comment: @mpatil I don't understand.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: this only helps me get the A column but I have the other columns listed I the queston. Also, it counts .5 as a numeric value but it is treated as a factor/object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it is however not exactly the same as you would need to replace nan values beforehand and drop unwated columns:

```
from collections import Counter
def func(ls):
    v,c = Counter(ls).most_common()[0]
    return 0 if v is '0' else c

df['v'] = df['values'].map(func)
df['v1'] = 1

df_all = df.pivot(columns=['v'], values=['v1']).fillna(0)
df_all.columns = ["all_" + str(x) for _,x in df_all.columns]

df.join(df_all).drop(['v', 'v1'], axis=1)

#   country region          values  all_0  all_1  all_2  all_3
# 0       A     CA   [0, 0, 1, .5]    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
# 1       B     NE    [0, 0, 0, 1]    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
# 2       C     CA   [1, 1, 1, .5]    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0
# 3       D     CA   [1, 0, 1, .5]    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0
# 4       E     EE  [0, .5, .5, 0]    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
# 5       F     NE    [0, 1, 1, 1]    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0
# 6       G     EE    [0, 0, 0, 0]    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
# 7       H     NE  [0, .5, 1, .5]    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0
# 8       I     EE        [nan, 0]    0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0
```